# Improve Code: Compare 2 list of elements

Tags: c#, optimization

sorry for the newbie question but, I'm new to programming..

I want to check if there's already no more than one element of `TypeA` in `listOfDifferentTypes`. I've following code:

```
     public void CheckType ( Object param)
     {
            if ( param is TypeA )
            {
                int i = 0;
                TypeA paramToCheck = ( TypeA ) param;

                foreach ( var paramB in listOfDifferentTypes )
                {
                    if ( paramB is TypeA )
                    {
                        var paramInList = ( TypeA ) paramB;
                        if ( paramToCheck.ID == paramInList.ID )
                        {
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ( i > 1 )
                {
                    paramToCheck.m_Error = "ErrorText";
                }    
            }
    }
```

I consider it's not very clean solution. Can this code be improved / optimized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use LINQ for this :) It will look nice:

```
//Checks for string - resplace <string> with <some type> for other types
private bool moreThanOne(List<object> differentTypes)
{
    return differentTypes.OfType<string>().Count() > 1;
}
```

Usage:

```
List<object> listOfDifferentTypes = new List<object> { "string", 13, 52, "string", 54.3f };

var res = moreThanOne(listOfDifferentTypes);
```

I see you also checks for some sort of ID then try this:

**UPDATED to do what your code is doing**

**Updated: replaced .Count() with .Skip(1).Any() so it will stop if more than 1 is found :)**

```
private void CheckType(object param, List<object> differentTypes)
{
    var paramToCheck = param as TypeA;

    if (paramToCheck == null) return;

    var res = differentTypes.OfType<TypeA>().Where(t => t.ID == paramToCheck.ID).Skip(1).Any();

    if (res) paramToCheck.m_Error = "error text";
}
```

As I have done, you can replace:

```
if (param is TypeA)
{
    TypeA paramToCheck = (TypeA) param;
    ... Do something
```

With:

```
TypeA paramToCheck = param as TypeA; //Returns null if not a TypeA
if (param == null) return;

... Do something
```

It is a little faster :)

Answer (score 1):

Your original solution, rewritten:

```
public void CheckType(Object param)
{
   TypeA paramToCheck = param as TypeA;
   int count = 0;
   if (paramToCheck != null)
   {
       foreach (var paramB in listOfDifferentTypes)
       {
           var paramInList = paramB as TypeA;
           if (paramInList != null && paramToCheck.ID == paramInList.ID)
           {
               count++;

               if (count > 1)
               {
                   paramToCheck.m_Error = "ErrorText";
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

}

Notes:

- use the `as` keyword with a comparison against `null` to perform type conversion,
- combine multiple conditions into a single `if` statement (using the AND (`&&`) operator),
- use the `break` statement to exit the `foreach` loop as soon as your condition has been satisfied.
- This is just a cleansed version of your original code; there are no doubt better ways to achieve your desired behaviour :-)

Edit: updated re: comments (thanks for pointing out my previous mistake!)

Comment: Hhm it is not exactly the same? Your code would write error if there is one or more instances. His code would write error if there is MORE THAN one instance. Correct me if I'm wrong :)